# Representing a vector-valued function in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell, iterable-unpacking

What is the best way to translate the following brief python/numpy code to matlab

```
from numpy import *

F = lambda x, y: (-y, x)

points = array(meshgrid([1,2,3], [4,5,6,7]))
vx, vy = F(*points)
print vx, vy
```

In the code above, `F` is intended to represent a vector-valued velocity field. Specfically, should a vector-valued function be represented using cells, or is there a better way to do it?

A first attempt to translate the above code:

```
F = @(x,y) {-y, x};

[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:3, 4:7);
rslt = F(X, Y); 
[vx, vy] = rslt{:};
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it? For example, could the anonymous function return more than one value so that one can call it like this `[vx, vy] = F(X,Y);` rather than having to define an intermediate `rslt` variable?

Answer (score 1):

You could split it into two functions:

```
%# each is a function of two variables
Fx = @(x,y) -y;
Fy = @(x,y) x;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:3, 4:7);
vx = Fx(X,Y);
vy = Fy(X,Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

It does seem strange that inline functions cannot return more than one output. Several workarounds are possible:

1. If the vectors are 2D, you can always pack them as a complex number.
2. You can just index the result. E.g. `v = f(x,y)` and use `v(1)` and `v(2)`
3. Use `deal` as follows:

   ```
   f=@(x,y) deal(-y, x)
   [a,b] = f(1,2)
   ```

   Returns: `a=-2` and `b=1`

The 2nd option is the cleanest, in my opinion (Or you can just declare a `function` instead of using an inline function. MATLAB now supports functions within functions, similar to python).